# Same buttons but looks differently WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button, styles

I have few buttons on my Window.xaml, 
interesting fact is that when I run app, they are looking different even if I used same code for each of them..

Here is screenshot:

[image]

It is possible to notice that their border does not look the same (esspecialy on Y button)..

Here is my code for each custom button: (X, Y and Z)

```
<Button x:Name="btnX"
        Grid.Column="1"
        FontSize="15"
        BorderThickness="1"
        Content="X"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
        Foreground="Black"
        Background="#d3d3d3"
        BorderBrush="Black" Margin="5">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>

    <Button x:Name="btnZ"
        Grid.Column="2"
        FontSize="15"
        Content="Z"
        BorderThickness="1"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
        Foreground="Black"
        Background="#d3d3d3"
        BorderBrush="Black" Margin="5">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>

    </Button>


        <Button x:Name="btnY"
        Grid.Column="2"
        Grid.Row="1"
        FontSize="15"
        Content="Y"
        BorderThickness="1"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
        Foreground="Black"
        Background="#d3d3d3"
        BorderBrush="Black" Margin="5">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: What's different?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal can't you notice that their borders are not looking the same? I used black border brush for each button and for some of them looks like I used gray acctualy.. ?

Answer (score 1):

I find out that setting `SnapsToDevicePixels="True"` and `UseLayoutRounding="True"` on my button fixed this issue, I'm not sure if that was best answer but that definately helped me..

Buttons after setting this properties:

[image]

Borders looks same now, and black as they should be.

Comment: `I'm not sure if that was best answer but that definately helped me.` It is. WPF uses subpixel rendering, which causes this kind of weird effect when the control is positioned between two pixels (usually because you have somewhere a container that use percentages for positioning). The properties you found slightly change the control's position so it fits the screen pixels. Why it isn't activated per default is beyond me.

Comment: @KevinGosse Yes, and I can tell it is really fine when BorderThickness is 1 but if you change it to 1.5 or smth, than it starts looking bad again, something like you gave top border 1.5 and bottom border 1.5 and rest is 1, really weird, so I will keep it on 1 px thickness right now.